# Tweaking incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION' and 'Top'

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017, ssms-2016

I very much appreciate your help on this one, would really like for someone to tell me why Select Distinct and UNION ALL errors and it appears that 'TOP' (1) also has some union issue with clause which I am not familiar with even after I have done my due diligence syntax research. Is it possible to link a second server with my query, I am simply trying to see if the second server needs a different format after "Select top (1)".

[Looking for this Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v3qX.png)

My error messages:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
'SERVER1' AS 'Server'
FROM (
Select top (1) with ties in.Name, in.Vendor, count(*) Count_InvoiceNo

FROM Data.dbo.Invoices AS in

where in.InvDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,-12, GETDATE())

group by in.Name, in.Vendor

order by rank() over(partition by in.Name order by count(*) DESC)) sq


UNION ALL



SELECT DISTINCT
'SERVER2' AS 'Server'
FROM (
Select top (1) with ties in.Name, in.Vendor, count(*) Count_InvoiceNo

FROM Data.dbo.Invoices AS in

where in.InvDate >= DATEADD(MONTH,-12, GETDATE())

group by in.Name, in.Vendor

order by rank() over(partition by in.Name order by count(*) DESC)) sq
```

Comment: You can't place an `ORDER BY` before a `UNION` it has to go at the very end. You'll need to use subqueries.

Comment: @Larnu  - do you have an example?

Comment: @Larnu - after adjusting ORDER BY, I remain with a different error. I am sure your not able to see my results, however, this is the other error:  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Msg 1062, Level 15, State 1, Line 32
The TOP N WITH TIES clause is not allowed without a corresponding ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

As I said:

> You can't place an `ORDER BY` before a `UNION` it has to go at the very end. You'll need to use subqueries

For example:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
        in.Name, in.Vendor, COUNT(*) Count_InvoiceNo
    FROM 
        Data.dbo.Invoices AS in
    WHERE 
        in.InvDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY
        in.Name, in.Vendor
    ORDER BY
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY in.Name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC))sq
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
        --'Server2' AS 'Server' --This column isn't in your top query
         in.Name, in.Vendor, COUNT(*) Count_InvoiceNo
    FROM 
        Analytics.dbo.Invoices AS in
    WHERE 
        in.InvDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY
        in.Name, in.Vendor
    ORDER BY
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY in.Name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)) sq;
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply DISTINCT 'Server2' AS 'Server', and TOP 1 on a single column ?

Comment: You don't apply `DISTINCT` to a column, you apply it to the dataset, @hmm4089 . With the `TOP (1) WITH TIES` it made little sense being in there as you should already be getting distinct results; if you weren't the `OVER` clause for your `RANK` was wrong.

Comment: I added 'Server1' AS 'Server' in top query and I only get 1 rows displaying 'Server', my sample data does not list.

Comment: If you add a column `server` to the top subquery, you'll need to uncomment the column in the bottom one, @hmm4089

Comment: @Lurna -  Will review your example.

Comment: larnu* @hmm4089 .

Comment: @Lurna - Query matches with servers, however it is not retrieving all lines for the in.Name, in.Vendor for the COUNT(*) Count_InvoiceNo.

Comment: - Query matches with servers, however it is not retrieving all lines for the in.Name, in.Vendor for the COUNT(*) Count_InvoiceNo.

Comment: Probably because of the `TOP` filtering them, "mhm4098".... You'll need to provide a sample data and expected results at this stage.

Comment: where do I provide sample data? I am not able to edit from my side.

Comment: You can always [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65010856/edit) your own post unless it has been locked.

Comment: @Lurna - I have edited and updated query and included image with needed line data listing rows.